# How can i normalize like these tables

Tags: database

i'm trying to normalize a table, that table  has attributes that attributes has  some sub-attributes those every sub-attributes also have another 2 sub-attributes

My table's attributes are

```
(
ZONE, 
Province, 
DISTRICT, 
YEAR,
MAHA SEASON {MAHA SEASON has seven sub-attributes they are 
    1.Banana [Banana has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. 
        ii.Ext.] 
    2. Okra [Okra has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. 
        ii.Ext.], 
    3. Winged Bean [Winged Bean has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. and 
        ii.Ext.], 
    4. Brinjal [Brinjal has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. and 
        ii.Ext.], 
    5. Capsicum [Capsicum has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. and 
        ii.Ext.], 
    6. Snake Gourd [Snake Gourd has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. and 
        ii.Ext.], 
    7. Tomato [Tomato has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. and 
        ii.Ext.]
    } , 
YALA SEASON {YALA SEASON has seven sub-attributes they are 
    1.Banana [Banana has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. 
        ii.Ext.] 
    2. Okra [Okra has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. 
        ii.Ext.], 
    3. Winged Bean [Winged Bean has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. and 
        ii.Ext.], 
    4. Brinjal [Brinjal has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. and 
        ii.Ext.], 
    5. Capsicum [Capsicum has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. and 
        ii.Ext.], 
    6. Snake Gourd [Snake Gourd has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. and 
        ii.Ext.], 
    7. Tomato [Tomato has two sub-attributes they are 
        i.Pro. and 
        ii.Ext.]
    }
)
```

for more details see the below image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk314.jpg)

any one please help me to normalize this table

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have two types of measurement - "pro" and "ext". Those measurements have a lot of attributes. Some of those attributes appear actually to be attributes of geographic entities.

```
province
----------
id (pk)
name

district
---------
id
name
province_id (fk)

location
----------
id int (pk)
zone (enum: wet/dry)
district_id (fk)

season
-------
id (pk)
name

measurement
----------
id (pk)
location_id (fk)
year
season_id (fk)
measurement_type (enum: pro/ext)
measurement (float)
```

Where I've specified enums, you may also want to change that to a foreign key relationship to a table listing the possible options. I prefer enums when the business domain will never change (e.g. "there will never be more than 7 days in a week"), and foreign keys when the business domain may change.

Comment: need to divide Four tables to contain details of Vegetable extent and production, district, Province, Seasons.

Comment: OK - it wasn't clear that "province", "district" were not free text fields, but I guess that makes sense - see the update.